# Is there something like cdots that uses less space?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

Is there an alternative where I still have three dots but less horizontal space is required?

For instance,

```
s_1s_2 \cdots s_L
```

results in:

[image]

I would like something more compact

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define your own version, with negative kerning:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand
  \Compactcdots{\mathinner{\cdotp\mkern-2mu\cdotp\mkern-2mu\cdotp}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\(s_1s_2 \cdots s_L\)

\(s_1s_2 \Compactcdots s_L\)

\end{document}
```

---

After egreg's comment:

Using the version above, with `\cdotp` (a `\mathpunct`), the space after each dot is `\thinmuskip` (which defaults to `3mu`), so `\cdotp\mkern-2mu\cdotp` is the same as `{{\cdot}\mkern3mu\mkern-2mu{\cdot}}` which is the same as `{{\cdot}\mkern1mu{\cdot}}`. `\cdot` is a `\mathbin`, so `{\cdot}` kills the spacing around it.

One difference between these is that with the former, if you change `\thinmuskip`, the spacing changes accordingly. With the second, the spacing is fixed:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand
  \Compactcdots{\mathinner{\cdotp\mkern-2mu\cdotp\mkern-2mu\cdotp}}

\DeclareRobustCommand
  \Fixedcdots{\mathinner{{\cdot}\mkern1mu{\cdot}\mkern1mu{\cdot}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*3{p{1.5cm}}}
  \(s_1s_2 \cdots s_L\) & \(s_1s_2 \Compactcdots s_L\) & \(s_1s_2 \Fixedcdots s_L\) \\
\end{tabular}

\thinmuskip=0mu
\begin{tabular}{*3{p{1.5cm}}}
  \(s_1s_2 \cdots s_L\) & \(s_1s_2 \Compactcdots s_L\) & \(s_1s_2 \Fixedcdots s_L\) \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

P.S. Don't *ever* use `\thinmuskip=0mu`.

Comment: Why not `{\cdot}\mkern1mu{\cdot}\mkern1mu{\cdot}`?

Comment: what would be the difference in that case?

Comment: Visually, none, as far as my myopia can see :P The `\cdot` is defined as a binary operator (`\mathbin`), so `{\cdot}` kills the binary spacing around it and the `\mkern1mu` adds some space. `\cdotp` (as I found out after egreg's comment) is defined as a punctuation (`\mathpunct`) and the negative kern kills some of the spacing. I don't know if there is another difference between one and another. @egreg?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The spacing after punctuation is governed by `\thinmuskip`, whose default value is `3mu`; adding `3mu` and subtracting `2mu`…

Comment: can we apply this for `\dots` instead of `\cdots`?

Comment: @alper Yes, just change `\cdotp` to `\ldotp` and `\cdot` to `.`: `\DeclareRobustCommand\Compactldots{\mathinner{\ldotp\mkern-2mu\ldotp\mkern-2mu\ldotp}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\Fixedldots{\mathinner{{.}\mkern1mu{.}\mkern1mu{.}}}`

Answer (score 3):

There are better answers above for "compacting" variations on cdots,
This answer is just to illustrate there is more to latex dots than may be obvious so without any manipulation dotsi (dots for integrals) generates a tighter overall length

[image]

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareRobustCommand % Copied for comparison with answer by Phelype Oleinik
\Compactcdots{\mathinner{\cdotp\mkern-2mu\cdotp\mkern-2mu\cdotp}}

\begin{document}

To indicate the omission of values in a repeated operation, a centred ellipsis is
used between two operation symbols (Midline horizontal ellipsis, or in LaTeX terms
three dots, centered). Due to it's ambiguity some authors [1] have recommended avoiding
its use in mathematics altogether.\\
\\
$s_1s_2\cdots s_L$ cdots\\
$s_1s_2\Compactcdots s_L$ Compactcdots\\
$s_1s_2\dotsb s_L$ dotsb\\
$s_1s_2\dotsi s_L$ dotsi\\
$s_1s_2\dotsm s_L$ dotsm\\

[1]  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis (cite ref-26) Roland Backhouse,\\
Program Construction: Calculating Implementations from Specifications.\\ Wiley (2003), page 138

\end{document}
```